# Require ruby gems in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger, rvm

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://google.com/")
```

This simple script works ok.

But if I'am trying to add
`require 'rubygems'` and `require 'mechanize'` to the Rails controller, server gives:

```
LoadError in NewsController#find
no such file to load -- mechanize
```

I use RVM on Ubuntu 10.04 server machnine. Ruby version: 1.9.2, Rails version: 3.0.3.
Server: Passanger under Apache2.

P.S. If I run `rails server` and go to mysite.com:3000 all works without any error, so there is a problem with Passanger!

Please, help me!

Comment: Have you installed the mechanize gem via gem install mechanize?  Only gems in your gemfile will install when you run bundler.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't require gems in your controller. Thats why Bundler was added to Rails 3.
Just add mechanize to your Gemfile like this

```
gem "mechanize"
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

on the command line.
Any gem mentioned here will be required on application startup.

Answer (score 5):

The way you manage dependencies in Rails 3, is [using the Gemfile and Bundler](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/bundler).

Edit your Gemfile and add

```
gem "mechanize"
```

Then run

```
$ bundle install
```

Restart the server. The library will automatically be loaded. No need to manually require RubyGems.